# How to configure remote iis server using Python

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, iis

We have a Windows server(iis) that we connect to using ssh(ubuntu) in python3 with paramiko library.

We want to do controls, for example:

- start/restart/stop/recycle <iis|app pool>.

also we can do it with:
iisreset or etc...

but we want do that in best practice method.

Comment: IIS can be automated via command line https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe or PowerShell, which you can call in Python scripts.

Comment: @LexLi
we install the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis-administration/  but how can start the api endpoint in remote address? 
are you work with this service?
that service is the best solution for us?

Comment: Why cannot you call `appcmd` directly, which is quite simple to follow? The REST API of course can be used, but there is not enough documentation on how to get started. You might dig into its source code on GitHub, or hire a consultant to help.

Comment: @LexLi because i want show result in another webpage in ubuntu server. appcmd results, shown in terminal with plaintext. and parse thats, take a time for writing code. i want a fast solution.